# libGDX change my system from pixels to units

Tags: java, libgdx

I want everyone to see the same things on their screen regardless of their screen size and aspect ratio so this is the code I am currently using. (also I am sending net data across with the coordinates of where the other players are on the screen)

```
int width = 1920, height = 1080;
 public OrthographicCamera camera;
 Viewport viewport;
//constructor
 camera = new OrthographicCamera();
  viewport = new ScalingViewport(Scaling.stretch, width, height, camera);
  viewport.apply();
  camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0);
  camera.update();

 public void resize(int width, int height) {
  viewport.update(width, height);
  camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0);
 }
```

now for example I wanted 10 perfect squares going across the middle of the screen so I made then 192 pixels by 192 pixels so I could have 10 perfect squares going across the middle of the screen my system right now works perfect except for the fact that it is rendered internally 1920x1080 on all devices big and small. How would I convert my camera to units and get the size needed for 10 perfect squares to go across the screen? Is that even possible?

Here is my code to draw 10 squares across the screen

```
    float size = 192;
    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        walls.add(new Stuff(i*size,height/2-size/2,size,size,"middle",1,1,0,1));
    }
```

How would I convert all this code to say units? Or is this an acceptable approach?

Comment: I missed your note earlier. Don't use Skype chat, but you can find me and PM me on the libgdx forum.

Answer (score 3):

You are already using units, they just aren't very meaningful (and it certainly aren't pixels). If you want to use meaningful units (e.g. SI units), then the only thing you have to change in this code are the values. E.g. if the size of your stuff (wall?) is, say 2 meter, then use the value 2 instead of 192. And if you want your users screen to be, say 20 meters (10 walls e.g.) in width and  16:9 aspect ratio, then use that for the Viewport worldWidth and worldHeight.

```
float worldWidth = 20;
float worldHeight = worldWidth * 9f / 16f;
...
viewport = new StretchViewport(worldWidth, worldHeight, camera);
```

Make sure to understand that these "pixels" you are talking about only exist in your imagination. See also: http://blog.xoppa.com/pixels/.

Answer (score 1):

You created your ScalingViewport with a width of 1920, so the width in world units will be 1920 on all screens, no matter what. Also, your scene will be distorted on any screen that is not 16:9, since you are stretching to fit whatever the screen is. (Because of the distortion, I personally would never use ScalingViewport with Scaling.stretch, aka StretchViewport.)

If you want your squares to look square on all screens with this type of viewport, you'll have to do some math to change their height (but their width should always be 192 if you want exactly ten to fit across the screen).

```
public void resize(int width, int height){
    float viewportAspect = 1920f / 1080f;
    float screenAspect = (float)width / (float)height; //Make sure you cast to floats
    boxHeight = 192 * screenAspect / viewportAspect;
    viewport.update(width, height, true);
}
```

The camera always shows the scene in world units, so there's no conversion to do.

Comment: If the user is not using a 16:9 screen I think they will have to deal with the stretching as I want everyone to see the same things on the screen. Unless I opted for the black bars which I think stretching will at least make some sort of use of the real estate. How can I unhook my game from pixels and render it in the native resolution of the device. Because right now I am basing all my code and shape drawing on pixels of an internal resolution of 1920x1080. Because wouldn't changing the heights of the squares change the physics simulation? I am sending this game over the network.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by unhooking from pixels because it seems like you already have. Based on what you said, you are doing everything like what you want. You are working in virtual units (virtual pixels) to fit a virtual 1920x1080 screen that is then stretched to fit the device screen.

Comment: I personally like ExtendViewport. It ensures a minimum viewable area and then you can just show extra scenery to fill in the extra area. For a puzzle game, you can just put extra background texture. For a platformer, it may be a bit trickier because you might want to make sure the player cannot see farther ahead and have extra advantage on certain shapes of screen. I do this in my one-way platformer by maintaining the player's max distance from the edge of the screen they are moving towards.